# Range filter gives values out of range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got a problem with my query :
I recive hits with StarDate out of filter range, for e.q 2016-09-07 ...

```
 "query" :{
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "range": {
            "StartDate" : { 
                "gte" : "2016-09-18 00:18:32"
        }
    }
},
"must" :{
"query_string":{
     "query":"WR_WRO_GGAJOWICKA_B"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `must` clause overrides the first one with the constraint on `StartDate`, and hence only the `query_string` query kicks in. You need to write your query like this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "StartDate": {
              "gte": "2016-09-18 00:18:32"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "WR_WRO_GGAJOWICKA_B"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```